# How can I create a temporary table in mariadb or mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mariadb, database-migration

Now, I'm migrating mssql to mariadb(mysql). Mssql has with clause(with A as ()), but mysql has not with clause. So I'm using "create temporary table", but some error occurred.

Example,

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TMP(
    SELECT CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %T.%f') AS CHAR(19)) AS REGDT
);
```

and this is error code

> MySQL Database Error: Truncated incorrect CHAR(19) value: '2016-06-27 10:34:34.000000'

What is wrong?

This is my query.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TMP(
  SELECT DEPTCODE, DEPTNAME, USEYN, HIGHDEPTCODE, 
         CAST(DATE_FORMAT(REGDT, '%Y-%m-%d %T.%f') AS CHAR(19)) AS REGDT,
         0 AS LEV, CAST(DEPTCODE AS CHAR(255)) AS SORT, DEPTORDER 
    FROM TBDEPARTMENT
   WHERE DEPTCODE = '1000');
```

Answer (score 2):

CHAR(19) is too small to store your whole date with milliseconds.

Use CHAR(26) instead:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TMP(
    SELECT CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %T.%f') AS CHAR(26)) AS REGDT
);
```

or remove the milliseconds:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TMP(
    SELECT CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %T') AS CHAR(19)) AS REGDT
);
```

You could also use a DATETIME type instead of a String.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!

Comment: Or don't store datetimes as strings (!?).   This is a `DATETIME(6)`, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

No bones are broken, so no `CAST` is needed:

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %T.%f');
+--------------------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %T.%f') |
+--------------------------------------+
| 2016-07-03 16:23:28.000000           |
+--------------------------------------+
```

If you are putting just one value in a table, consider using an @ variable:

```
mysql> SELECT @regdt := DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %T.%f');
+------------------------------------------------+
| @regdt := DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %T.%f') |
+------------------------------------------------+
| 2016-07-03 16:26:07.000000                     |
+------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @regdt;
+----------------------------+
| @regdt                     |
+----------------------------+
| 2016-07-03 16:26:07.000000 |
+----------------------------+
```