# Creating new data table on existing one

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datatable

Hello I've got a question, how (if it possible), I can create new datatables with close same rows but if In column value is in string "/" for example

| ID | column_param | column_sym | column_value | column_val2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | param_test1 | ABC | 11/12 | test |
| Second | param_test2 | CDE | 22/11 | test |
| Third | param_test3 | EFG | 44 | teste |
| 4'th | param_test4 | HIJ | 33/22 | test |

And here if I have `param_test1` and `param_test4` and if in this column value has "/" I want to create 2 other rows but if I will not set `param_test2` then it stay as it is and everything should be in new datatable. Is any way to create this?
Thank you in advance.

Expected result:

[image: ExpectedResult]

Comment: Very much lost in translation..can you add your expected outcome please,

Comment: Ok, I edited post with expected result

Comment: Is it possible that `param_test1` or `param_test4` row have according `column_value` (1) without `/`? (2) with more than one `/`? (3) with equal parts (for example, `'12/12'`)?

Comment: Yes it is possible, not every param_test1 has "/" and sometimes there is more than (1) "/"

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version?

Comment: (3) no there isn't possible to have params with equal parts

Comment: Server version 10.4.17

Comment: Ok so actually mariadb not mysql..

Comment: Yes, MariaDB, my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- As per Gordon's answer, I'm not sure what should be done with the your ID column.
  I've replaced these with row numbers.
- Depending on your version of MySQL/MariaDB, the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function may not be available. Depending on whether IDs in the output are necessary you may be able to simply omit this.
- I've assumed the existence of a table called `myNumbers` which contains a single field `num` and is populated with positive integers from 1 to whatever you're likely to need.

I've included more in the output that you asked for, which will hopefully help you understand what's going on

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY d.ID, n.num) as NewID,
    d.ID as OriginalID,
    n.num as,
    d.column_param,
    d.column_sym,
    d.column_value as orig_value,
    CASE WHEN column_param = 'param_test2' THEN d.column_value
    ELSE substring_index(substring_index(d.column_value,'/',n.num),'/',-1) END as split_value,
    d.column_val2
FROM
    myData d
    JOIN myNumbers n on char_length(d.column_value)-char_length(replace(d.column_value,'/','')) >= n.num-1
WHERE
    n.num = 1 OR d.column_param <> 'param_test2'
ORDER BY
    d.ID,
    n.num
```

See this [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3QHVFrkcANX6uyfp1BSU6q/0) (the columns output in a different order than I've specified, but I think that's a DB Fiddle quirk).

If you only want to "split" say `param_test1` and `param_test4` rows the code above code could be amended as follows:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY d.ID, n.num) as NewID,
    d.ID as OriginalID,
    d.column_param,
    d.column_sym,
    n.num,
    d.column_value as orig_value,
    CASE WHEN column_param NOT IN ('param_test1','param_test4') THEN d.column_value
    ELSE substring_index(substring_index(d.column_value,'/',n.num),'/',-1) END as split_value,
    d.column_val2
FROM
    myData d
    JOIN myNumbers n on char_length(d.column_value)-char_length(replace(d.column_value,'/','')) >= n.num-1
WHERE
    n.num = 1 OR d.column_param  IN ('param_test1','param_test4')
ORDER BY
    d.ID,
    n.num
```

Comment: ID is just a number, I'll not do anythink with ID. And I'll check your answer :)

Comment: 1 more question is it possible to change "param_test2" to only "param_test1 and param_test4" and inverse this query a little bit because params like "param_test1" I've got a few, but params like "param_test2" I've got many thousands, and I want to only divide rows  with params like "param_test1" or "param_test4"

Comment: Yes, if you have only a few different `column_param` values which need splitting, and many that don't, that would make sense. I'll post a tweaked version shortly.

Comment: Nice, thank you very much I'll test that. I hope it will work :) It would save my life :D

Comment: If it works, then come back and upvote and accept the answer to help others find useful stuff. If it doesn't work, then comment accordingly and we'll see if we can fix it.

Comment: Okej I'll, but one more question I've got info (error) that "myNumbers" table doesn't exist, I change everything as should it be but only this one left, I thought this is virtual table, what should I change in this? I also deleted two rows under select because I'll not use that

Comment: A "numbers" table can be quite useful and may be worth creating. You can see how in my DB Fiddle. If you don't want to do that, you could create it as a temporary table (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38044911/how-can-i-create-a-temporary-table-in-mariadb-or-mysql). Such tables only exist while you run the code.

Comment: Okej, I can create then datatable like "numbers" but Have I add any numbers to that? I've got huge DB and there is a lot of numbers like in example "1/5" etc. Or this numbers are just from 1 to 5?

Comment: Just for whole numbers as per my DB Fiddle. You said you might have more than one `/`, so you need all the whole numbers from 1 to however many items might be stored separated by `/`s. So if your longest one is `123/456/789` you'd only need the numbers 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: It is used to help pick out the substring which corresponds to the number from that table. So when using the row with number `3`, for my last example, it would extract `789`.

Comment: OK, everythink is working fine :D, thank you very much, I check your answer as correct and usefull. Really really thanks for you

Comment: Last one If I can :), If I want add this to new datatable then shoud I just type INSERT and this query put inside this?

Comment: Apologies for my slow response. Yes, that's basically the way to do it. See this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595252/mysql-creating-a-new-table-with-information-from-a-query#:~:text=You%20can%20do%20it%20like,table%20should%20be%20created%20from.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the `id` is being set, but you can do what you want using `union all`:

```
select column_param, column_sym,
       substring_index(column_value, '/', 1) as column_value,
       column_val2
from t
union all
select column_param, column_sym,
       substring_index(column_value, '/', -1) as column_value,
       column_val2
from t
where column_value = '%/%';
```